# How can I improve read operations on a huge table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssas

I have a huge table with around 350 million rows which are updated every now and then(approx every row - once in 5 mins) and the update is done in batches (updating multiple rows together like 100 rows at a time)

Now in a seperate application i need to run queries at regular intervals(say 5 mins) which are taking a long time if done in a normal way.

I need suggestions on how can i do it in a performance efficient way. Are analysis Services meant for such a task?

Please provide your inputs / thoughts / comments on this.

Regards
Shruti

Comment: What exactly are those other queries you are running from a separate application? Without knowing them there's no way of telling which index(es) you need to create.

Comment: SQL Server Analysis Services (SSAS) is for Data Mining and Business Intelligence. You have to provide more context to your problem. What kind of queries are you running ? What is the NORMAL way of running them?

Comment: Excuse me for my ignorance in database concepts. I need to run select * queries using joins from multiple tables in that database.  By normal way , i meant writing queries from .Net code. But the problem is that , when i run such queries, they take many minutes to execute and meanwhile if there is an update operation to be done on that table, it gets blocked. Hence the performance of the original application is getting hampered.

Comment: I think you need to provide a little more detail, but I'll provide a very generic answer...

Comment: I cant use query notifications because i guess they jus inform that there is a change in my desired tables. I will still have to query that data from those tables.

Comment: @Shruti Can you please update your question with those queries? Without them it's not possible to know what you need to improve.

Comment: Let me know if i m missing something important and useful :(

Comment: Maybe you could use indexed views?

Comment: I will try and explain the scenario in little detail. There is a table with the following columns - devID,attributeID,dcsValue,dcsChangeStamp,dcsDateModified. This table has around 350 millions rows. Now in the other application, i have to continuously monitor for a particular attribute ID and dcsValue. Now in no way, i can afford to affect the performance of the application that is writing to this table.

Comment: If the writes have priority, then how "stale" can the reads be? Can they be a minute behind, 5 minutes, an hour? One idea would be to replicate the table either in whole or, using the trigger methodology mentioned elsewhere below, only the rows that are important. I don't necessarily mean SQL Server replication but any form of making a read-only copy of the table - log shipping, mirroring w/snapshots, your own custom job, etc. You can also consider having the application write in two places.

Answer (score 3):

1 - Make sure you have a proper index structure.  Bear in mind that indexes slow down writes and updates.  As a rule **EVERY** index is updated whenever you insert or update a row.  This can lead to locking as well.

2 - How important is consistency between reads and writes?  Is it mission-critical that each query have the most recent record from every row in the last update? If it's not, you can use locking hints such as `WITH (NOLOCK)` in your select statements which will give you potentially out-of-date records (if they are being updated as you are reading them) but will bypass row-level locks and now wait for the `UPDATE` or `INSERT` to complete.

Comment: I cannot probably change the database structure/indexing. I can only read the database for use in my application.

Comment: @Shruti - Are the `INSERT` or `SELECT` more mission critical?  It sounds like you need to give precedence to one of them.

Comment: Ofcourse.. Insert is at a higher priority since that will will update with latest values on which the second application needs to operate.

Comment: @Shruti - I would recommend a `TABLOCK` hint and/or a transaction for your inserts to prevent issues with concurrent reads, then.

Comment: But the problem is that if the read is happening (which will take time of the order of mins) and write has to happen at the same time, the performance of the application writing data will get hampered (which is not permissible).

Comment: If you use `NOLOCK` on the reads it shouldn't affect the write much at all, but you may get out-of-date data.

Comment: Do you need to read all 350 million rows in yur select statements, or only some of them?

Answer (score 1):

As this is an extremely generic question, I can only provide an extremely generic reply.

1) Indexes do add overhead to Inserts etc, but they are often marginal compared to the performance gains elsewhere. Use appropriate indexes to improve your apps select performance.

2) I'm inferring that you're reading more often that you're writing. You may benefit from having triggers pre-calculate an intermediate result for you, stored in another table. Depending on the nature of the writes, you may need to delete an re-calculate from scratch, or just calculate the effects of the change (using both the `deleted` and `inserted` tables).

**EDIT**

If you're monitoring for particular write; create a trigger on the table.

You then only need to check the data being written, not the whole table.

Comment: I will try and explain the scenario in little detail. There is a table with the following columns - devID,attributeID,dcsValue,dcsChangeStamp,dcsDateModified. This table has around 350 millions rows. Now in the other application, i have to continuously monitor for a particular attribute ID and dcsValue. Now in no way, i can afford to affect the performance of the application that is writing to this table.

Comment: @Shruti: Put the indexes on a separate physical volume. You should be doing this anyway, but it will also improve performance.

Comment: Or do what our ####ing IT dept do, partition a single drive in order to put .ldf and .mdf files (etc) on different drives.  (This is sarcasm.)

Answer (score 0):

And while you are at it, do NOT ever use SELECT * queries on production especially when you have joins. You are returning more data than you need (the join fields contain the same data) which is wasteful of network and server resources. Take the extra ten seconds once to put in only the fields you need to have a better performing query every time it is run.

Then look at the queries you are running for other performance enhancements. There are a lot of ways you can write a badly performing query and in a system as you describe, you simply can't afford to do that. Get yourself a book on performance tuning and thoroughly read the chaptes on tuning queries. Then read the rest. In a system this large, performance tuning is a critical skill. You can't get awy with not knowing database concepts and internals and querying in depth anymore when you work on something this large.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps could you also consider doing [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcbchxcb%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) (though not likely if you cannot change the database structure):

```
ALTER DATABASE [your database]
SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON;
```

Remarks: in this case 1) selects will not block updates and vice versa 2) you will "see the latest committed data" 3) there is an extra overhead to store the row versions in `tempdb`.

See the last paragraphs of this [good post](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2011/07/difficulty-deadlocks/).

See also: [Choosing Row Versioning-based Isolation Levels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188277.aspx)